# How to Implement Radar View for Locations on Map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I used several applications that are providing "radar view" for listing locations on map. I have been searching for examples or guidelines but I probably choose wrong keywords, I'm not sure why, I had no results.

I simply attached an image because it's hard to explain this feature but I'm sure there are people making this in their projects.

For the ones who does not know, radar view works on camera and shows locations that you marked on the direction you turn the camera. Moreover, some usages are providing the distance etc. but that's not primarily objective for me.

Hope to get some help, thanks in advance.

[image: Radar View in iPhone]

P.S. The name of the application is 'Turkcell Pusula' in store, left is normal view, right is radar view as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "augmented reality" and that's a short tutorial using 3DAR for this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPSD2LoUi3c&feature=related

Also, there are some repositories using 3DAR:
https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=Objective-C&q=3dar&repo=&langOverride=&x=18&y=11&start_value=1